# How to know when images in an html fragment have been loaded after jquery's .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I load an html fragment that contains images with jquery's `.load()`, the images aren't yet loaded when my callback is called. Since I need to do some calculations based on the dimensions of the images, I need to know when they've actually been loaded. Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

`imageElement.onload = callback;`